Error connecting to On-Premises SQL from Data Factory
Im trying to connect my On-premises SSMS to Azure Data factory for data migration. When I'm creating a linked service and testing it, I'm getting this:

Cannot connect to SQL Database. Please contact SQL server team for further support. Server: 'IBRAHIM\SQLEXPRESS', Database: 'AdventureWorks2017', User: 'admin'. Check the linked service configuration is correct, and make sure the SQL Database firewall allows the integration runtime to access.
A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)
The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted

I'm getting this error, can someone suggest me what should I do to resolve this error?
I have tried adding the firewall rules like adding TCP 1433. Earlier I do not have to do anything to connect via SHIR. But now I'm facing this error.

Hi Ibrahim and welcome to Stack Overflow. The error seems to be in the message. In short: connection successfully established, but error occurred during login. Certificate chain issued by authority that is not trusted.

This error typically occurs when SQL is using a certificate that isn’t trusted by the client machine. This is most probably since it's SQL Express, and not a full SQL Server product.
Here are a few options to resolve the issue:

Install a Trusted Certificate
Make sure your SQL Server is using a certificate issued by a trusted Certificate Authority. You could for instance get a free certificate from Let’s Encrypt. Install the cert on your machine running SQL and make sure it’s in the trusted root store of the client machine.

Modify the Connection String
Quick fix 1: modify your connection string to include TrustServerCertificate=True. This will bypass the certificate validation, but it’s not recommended for production environments due to security risks.

Disable Encryption
Quick fix 2: set Encrypt=False in your connection string. This will disable encryption, which is also not recommended for production environments.


Also see:

"The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted" when connecting DB in VM Role from Azure website
How to fix SQL Server 2019 connection error due to certificate issue


Thanks for your help Rick. I solved it by clicking the Trust server certificate check box while creating the Linked Service.

You're welcome! Please click 'Accept answer' if it helped solve the issue. This will help future viewers of the question to find the answer quicker.
